# concept on download a big file in ios

Tags: ios, swift

i like to download a big file from a IOS app to the local disk.
I do not know howto start. I found a lot of threads mentoining different methods, but I don't know which way to go.

Perhabs someone can help me bringing to the right way with a rough concept ?

my prerequisites:
- File is about 300 MB
- I like to show the progress in a dialog.
- I prefere to do this in swift.

any hints ?

Additional Info about my conceptual problem:
At start I would like to show a Welcomepage with a Progressbar during load of data.
When load is finished I would like to show a custom view representing the loaded data.
Now I don't know howto do that.
In a Android App I would have a main activity (which is probably similar to a ViewController ?) then I will show a customdialog with a progressbar. When finished loading I would close the dialog and add some views in my Mainactivity.

How would an IOS developer do that ?

There are two cases to handle this in foreground and in background. In Android this can be done using service.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use NSURLSession class for download task. This will also work in background if *background fetch* is enabled in capabilities in xcode.

Comment: Will I see a progressbar anywhere when using NSURLSession class, or can I fetch the downloadstate to update a progressbar which is in a ViewController ?

Comment: You need to implement this progressbar. You will get total content size in response header and size of data downloaded. using this information you can show progressbar

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how gets it updated during download. Will this be refreshed automatically ?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried it before with NSURLSession... I used NSURLConnection for small data and it has this provision..but not sure about NSURLSEssion